# Jquery Mobile - how to run a plugin at mobileinit using Jquery widget factory

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-mobile

I have some jquery-scripts which I want to put into a plugin.

In my current setup the code is executed at "mobileinit" with my custom.js file sitting between Jquery.js and Jquery Mobile.js files.

This is what I'm doing:

```
(function($ , window, undefined) {
$( window.document ).bind('mobileinit', function(){
          alert ("init");
 });     
})(jQuery,window);
```

I would like to make this into a plugin using the Jquery Widget factory as recommended by [JQM-developers](https://gist.github.com/1071960)

Currently I'm stuck with the following:

```
(function( $, window, undefined ){
   $.widget( "myPlugin", $.mobile.widget, {
        options: { },
        _create: function() {$.fn.myPlugin = function() {       
          alert ("init");          
           };
   $( window.document ).bind('mobileinit', function(){ {
     myPlugin();
     });
})( jQuery, window );
```

which does not work... if I put the plugin.js before JQM.js "mobile isn't defined". If I put it afterwards, nothing happens.

My question: 
How can make a widget which runs on mobileinit, that is before Jquery Mobile.js is running.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. Here is a roundup of possibilities - you can do either of the following:

1. bind to JqueryMobile **`pagecreate`** event ([see here](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html)):
   This fires after elements have been enhanced, but before the page is shown
2. bind to JqueryMobile **`pageinit`** event ([same link](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html)):
   This way you can make changes to the JQM widgets before they enhance elements on a page. This should be the equivalent to `$(document).ready()`

However, if you want to change JQM core itself, you need to bind to earlier events.

1. bind to JqueryMobile **`mobileinit`** event ([same link](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html)):
   You can only override Jquery Mobile stuff set (itself set at `mobileinit`) by putting your plugin file BEFORE Jquery-Mobile.js. However this way you can no longer use the widget factory structure recommended by Jquery Mobile, because it requires Jquery-Mobile.js to run first.

I'm currently checking to see if I can bind to  **`DOMContentLoaded`**, too. Maybe this is another solution

Answer (score 1):

Got an answer somewhere else. I need to bind to JQM pagecreate event and put the pluing after Jquery loads, but before JQM loads. Works fine.